# How To Generate A Spinner in Android With Java?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I want to add a spinner to my android app from my Java code without the need to touch xml file, so I did some search and found some code that will do some of that, but it still used "findViewById" to get the spinner from xml, I replaced that with : Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);

Yet in the code it has "R.layout.spinner_item", in my case how to by pass that ? The code looks like this :

```
final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);
String[] plants = new String[]{"Laceflower", "California sycamore", "Mountain mahogany", "Butterfly weed", "Carrot weed"};
final List<String> plantsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(plants));
final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, plantsList)     <--- ?
{
  @Override
  public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
  {
    View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView tv = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    if (position % 2 == 1)
    {
      tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF7C7967"));
      tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFC3C0AA"));
    }
    else
    {
      tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF657A86"));
      tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFB5DCE8"));
    }
    return view;
  }
};

spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);     <--- ?
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: You have to use a layout ID in the constructor of ArrayAdapter, but you can go ahead and use a default android value for this if you don't want to create an xml file. You don't need to do it when creating the spinner though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like below to create `Spinner` at runtime without `layout` file

```
//Create spinner dynamically
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(context);

//Ready your data for spinner
String[] plants = new String[]{"Laceflower", "California sycamore", 
        "Mountain mahogany", "Butterfly weed", "Carrot weed"};

//Create ArrayAdapter for spinner with system default layout for views
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
        plants
);

//Attach adapter to spinner
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```